# Постоянное соединение с веб-сервером

Tags: c++, веб-сервер, веб-программирование, сокеты, winsock

Пишу подобие веб-сервера на С++, при подключении отправляю клиенту ответ с "Connection: Keep-Alive" и не закрываю соединение. При обращении к серверу (браузер Google Chrome) содержимое страницы загружается, но хром не понимает, что загрузка ответа завершилась(CAUTION: request is not finished yet!). Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Вы Content-length правильно выставляете ?

Comment: К сожалению, да, проверил ещё раз, все верно

Comment: Видимо, всё же не совсем верно, раз Хром так считает. Можете составить минимальный пример, чтобы воспроизвести это?